# Why my machine, automatically goes to this IP/domains

Tags: macos, dns, internet, url, network

Why my machine, automatically goes to this IP/domains. I have installed VM with windows 7 and I have wordpress site with xammp server and that is all. Is they are safe domains or not? Because I see bing.com in the end of the first domain. 
1.foodanddrink.tile.appex.bing.com
2.init-p01md-lb.push-apple.com.akadns.net
IP- 95.180.157.187 or 95.180.157.193
Are anyone has same issue is that are some services from Microsoft, apple or are some bad links. When I googled for first domain I found this.

https://www.threatcrowd.org/domain.php?domain=foodanddrink.tile.appex.bing.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bing.com domain is used by Microsoft to serve information for the "Food and Drink" tile that's in Windows. It is not a "bad link".

The push-apple.com.akadns.net domain is used by Apple to provide push notification services to macOS  / iOS. It is not a bad link.

The IP-addresses are registered as Macedonian. It is not possible to say whether they're good or bad in that context.

Comment: The IP addresses give it me with that host addresses.
Do you know why my machine approaches to foodanddrink.tile.appex.bing.com what is that, is that some service from Microsoft. How to stop going to that addresses.

For example, you can see many URLs similar to "foodanddrink.tile.appex.bing.com" mentioned in the question in this address:
[link](https://otx.alienvault.com/indicator/hostname/foodanddrink.tile.appex.bing.com?utm_medium=InProduct&utm_source=ThreatCrowd)

Comment: When you open the "Start" menu in Windows, you get a number of tiles (i.e. flat, colored rectangles) that can contain various information such as weather, calendar information, etc. One of those is Food and Drinks. If you want to avoid that, remove that tile - but it is not malicious in any way.

Comment: OK, thank you so much for good explanation

Answer (score 0):

It appears the IP address range is used by youtube.

```
inetnum: 95.180.157.0 - 95.180.157.255
netname: NEOTEL-NET
descr: NEOTEL-MKD Youtube
country: MK
admin-c: NCR6-RIPE
tech-c: NCR6-RIPE
status: ASSIGNED PA
remarks: INFRA-AW
mnt-by: MNT-NEOTEL
created: 2011-05-11T13:57:50Z
last-modified: 2015-07-21T08:07:38Z
source: RIPE
```

Comment: Your answer would be much more useful if you explain how you gathered this information. Can you please edit that directly into your answer?